# Partial HTTP response when using BIO_read

Tags: c++, http, ssl, https, openssl

Is it possible to get HTTP response from server using BIO_read (C++)?

When I tried to use `BIO_read(bio, buffer, sizeof(buff))` for http responses - in buffer I get only some of the response, not all.

If it is possible show an example of getting full response, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to get HTTP response from server using BIO_read

Yes.

---

> If it is possible show an example of getting full response, please

From  [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSS wiki:

```
#define HOST_NAME "www.random.org"
#define HOST_PORT "443"
#define HOST_RESOURCE "/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=32&format=h"
...

BIO *web = NULL, *out = NULL;
...

BIO_puts(web, "GET " HOST_RESOURCE " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
              "Host: " HOST_NAME "\r\n"
              "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
BIO_puts(out, "\n");
...

int len = 0;
do
{
  char buff[1536] = {};
  len = BIO_read(web, buff, sizeof(buff));

  if(len > 0)
    BIO_write(out, buff, len);

} while (len > 0 || BIO_should_retry(web));
```

You should notice two things. First, the return value of `BIO_read` is checked. Second, `BIO_should_retry` is used to detect if there's more data to read due to potential races.

Its *not* a *full example*. What should happen in production is you perform a partial read on the `BIO`. You determine the length of the response from the response header. Then you add a third condition with a safety valve - the expected response length. You need a safety valve for broken web servers and broken proxies that provide the wrong response length.

*If* you remove the `Connection: close` from the HTTP request, then you will need to parse the HTTP response and get the expected length. The above code mostly works because the server closes the connection, and that serves as an out of band signal you can use to fully receive the response.

Comment: Can I print the server answer with Cout, not BIO_write?